# cassandra hector authentication error

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am trying to access Cassandra database using Hector api 1.1-4 and i have authentication and authorization enabled in Cassandra . here is my code for creating cluster:

cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("Test Cluster", "localHost:9160", credentials);

but unfortunately it gives me error :

The method getOrCreateCluster(String, CassandraHostConfigurator, Map) in the type HFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, Map)

Answer (score 1):

You're supplying the second parameter as a String and the error is telling you that you need to supply a `CassandraHostConfigurator` object. Build the object as:

```
CassandraHostConfigurator hostConfig = new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160");
```

And now try supplying the new parameters.

```
HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("Test Cluster", hostConfig, credentials);
```

p.s. the [wiki](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/wiki/User-Guide#basic-configuration-and-setup) one-lines this, so feel free to do the same.

Comment: that error is fine but i get a new error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/thrift/Compression

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means you dont have the Class that is mention in the exception in your classpath. It basically means you are missing a dependency, in this case its the [Thrift](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.thrift/libthrift) jar you are after to satisfy said dependency.What version you want depends on the hector version.

Comment: Thrift is available till 0.9 but I am working on Cassandra 2.0.3 Will 0.9 work with cassandra 2.0.3?